# Muon update manager icon in system tray not updating

Tags: kde, update-manager, system-tray, kde5, muon-package-manager

Kubuntu 15.10. Muon update manager system tray icon indicating updates available. Click on icon, click on update, manager downloads and installs updates successfully and indicates that system is up to date. Close updater. System tray icon still shows updates available. Doesn't seem to refresh. Bring up manager again which indicates system up to date. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I've got the same issue. As does this guy. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BM5FOY0tXU

Comment: I have the same issue. I realized the follwoing: I unchecked the Update icon in the System Tray Settings and clicked  Apply. Then I cehcked it again and clicked apply again. Now the iccon shows the correct status.

Comment: Here is a bug report on the issue https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347602

Answer (score 0):

This is a confirmed bug of KDE 5: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347602

My suggestion is to wait until it is fixed. It is also suggested that using the update widget instead of the update icon in the system tray widget would work: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347602#c26